# how to remove the contents of a column without deleting the column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to delete the contents of a column but would like to keep the column.

For instance I have a table like.

| Numbers1 | Numbers2 | Numbers3 | Numbers4 | Numbers5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| five | four | three | two | two |
| six | seven | eight | nine | ten |
| nine | seven | four | two | two |
| seven | six | five | three | one |

I would like to remove all the contents of column b but I want to keep column Numbers2

the desired output be like

| Numbers1 | Numbers2 | Numbers3 | Numbers4 | Numbers5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| five |  | three | two | two |
| six |  | eight | nine | ten |
| nine |  | four | two | two |
| seven |  | five | three | one |

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
df['Numbers2']=''  #empty string

df['Numbers2']=np.nan #nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply assign an "empty" value (NaN, empty string, None, whatever you want):

```
df['Numbers2'] = float('NaN')
```

output:

```
  Numbers1  Numbers2 Numbers3 Numbers4 Numbers5
0     five       NaN    three      two      two
1      six       NaN    eight     nine      ten
2     nine       NaN     four      two      two
3    seven       NaN     five    three      one
```

With empty string:

```
df['Numbers2'] = ''

  Numbers1 Numbers2 Numbers3 Numbers4 Numbers5
0     five             three      two      two
1      six             eight     nine      ten
2     nine              four      two      two
3    seven              five    three      one
```

Answer (score 0):

update it with a empty string

```
df['Numbers2']=""
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you could delete the column with `df = df.drop('Numbers2', axis=1)`

Second, replace the column with `df['Numbers2'] = ""`